# Javac giving an error while trying to compile all java files in a folder using linux script

Tags: bash, command-line, javac

I have a script which has the following

```
#!/bin/bash
javac -classpath /netweka/weka-3-6-10/weka.jar ./*.java
```

when I try to run this script on a Linux terminal, I get an error saying :

```
: not found
javac: invalid flag:
Usage: javac  
use -help for a list of possible options
: not found*.java
```

I want to compile all the java files in the current directory. What am I missing ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try: `javac -classpath /netweka/weka-3-6-10/weka.jar *.java`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you created that script file in Windows, and it has Windows (cr-lf) line endings. Those won't work with Linux utilities, because the CR (`0x0D`, `control-M`, or `\r`) is considered a regular character. In this case, it's become part of the glob `./*.java\r`, which therefore (a) matches nothing, and (b) inserts a carriage return in the middle of the error message making it hard to read.

Convert your script to Linux line endings, using a Linux text editor, `dos2unix` or `tr -d $'\r' < old > new` where `old` and `new` are the input and output files.

Comment: tr -d $'\r' old > new ( replacing the old with my old filename and new with a new filename) does not work